# IndexError: Caught IndexError in replica 0 on device 0. IndexError: index 8 is out of bounds for dimension 0 with size 8

Tags: object-detection, huggingface-transformers

I'm trying to finetune detr model. Here's my pipeline:

```
from transformers import TrainingArguments

training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir = "detr_parameters",
    per_device_train_batch_size=8,
    num_train_epochs=10,
    fp16=True,
    save_steps=200,
    logging_steps=50,
    learning_rate=1e-5,
    weight_decay=1e-4,
    save_total_limit=2,
    remove_unused_columns=False,
)

from transformers import Trainer

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    data_collator=collate_fn,
    train_dataset=dataset_train_transform,
    tokenizer=image_processor,
)

trainer.train()
```

To be honest, the same pipeline was working and training yesterday, but today this error keeps appearing.

I tried to find the same errors on the Internet, but I couldn’t find them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what broke it, but it has to do with the amount of GPUs. The DETR receives `BatchSize*NumGpus` samples and that causes the overflow. As a workaround limit the training to one GPU:

```
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 ./train.py
```